# Node.JS GET / Parameters

Tags: node.js, express, query-string, body-parser

For exemple this is my server with a simple API :

```
var express = require('express');
var rzServer = express();
rzServer.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
rzServer.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/url', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.query.data); // String
   console.log(JSON.parse(req.query.date)); // Object
});
```

req.query.data is interpreted as a string but it's a JSON Object.

Is it possible with the body-parser package to parse the querystring ?

Thanks.

Comment: Body parser only parses the incoming body on POST requests.

Comment: Okay, That answers my question, Thanks ^^

Comment: JSON.parse is your friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*body-parser* is a middleware to **parse body** (it's its name). If you want to parse the query string, so you need another middleware for that.

Another thing : **GET** requests normally don't take any JSON parameters (no body). If you need to send a true JSON, perhaps you're not using the good HTTP method. Try to use a **POST** request, or create a true query string (http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#req.query).